# Packet injection in a Wi-Fi network with card in monitor mode

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark, wifi-configuration

I have a computer connected to a WEP-protected Wi-Fi network. With scapy I can forge packets (let's say ICMP) and send them to another station of the same network.

If I put my wireless card in monitor mode, I automatically quit the network, and I can't send my forged packet (or whatever other packet, like a ping request) to the network. A wireshark sniffing the network confirms than I don't send anything on it.

If I use aireplay, it says that injection is working:

```
# aireplay-ng -9 wlan0mon
08:07:32  Trying broadcast probe requests...
08:07:32  Injection is working!
08:07:34  Found 1 AP 

08:07:34  Trying directed probe requests...
08:07:34  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - channel: 11 - 'skynet'
08:07:35  Ping (min/avg/max): 13.227ms/41.702ms/121.679ms Power: -18.77
08:07:35  30/30: 100%
```

And I can use the aircrack-ng suite just fine, so I guess that my card is compatible. The card is an `Atheros Communications, Inc. TP-Link TL-WN821N v3 / TL-WN822N v2 802.11n [Atheros AR7010+AR9287]`.

So two questions:

- how can I send packets when in monitor mode?
- or how can I sniff the network without being in monitor mode?